# Python: Updating within a loop

Tags: python, api, while-loop

So I am attempting to create a little program that interacts with the music server Volumio via Volumio's REST API (Documentation here: https://volumio.github.io/docs/API/REST_API.html). Basically, my program should take a command as an input, translate it to a REST API request, send the request, and print out the status and the title of the song. I recognize that there is room for an invalid command to be entered here but it's not currently my concern. My concern is that the output after a command is entered is wrong. Here is the code:

```
import json
import requests

def controls(cmd):
        volumio = requests.get("http://volumio.local:3000/api/v1/getstate")
        vol_data = volumio.text
        py_data = json.loads(vol_data)
        if cmd == 'getstate':
                 print(py_data['title'], py_data['status'])
        else:
                requests.get("http://volumio.local:3000/api/v1/commands/?cmd=%s" % cmd)
                print(py_data['title'], py_data['status'])
while True:
        input = raw_input('Command: ')
        controls(input)
```

Basically, after submitting the command 'pause' for example, the output should be:

```
(u'04 - The Woods.mp3', u'pause')
```

Then upon 'play'ing again:

```
(u'04 - The Woods.mp3', u'play')
```

'next' should simply change the song name and keep the status the same. But here is my output when I run:

```
Command: play
(u'04 - The Woods.mp3', u'pause')
Command: play
(u'04 - The Woods.mp3', u'play') #showing the state from line 1 command
Command: getstate
(u'04 - The Woods.mp3', u'play') #shows correct updated state
Command: next
(u'04 - The Woods.mp3', u'play') #showing wrong song title
Command: getstate
(u'A.T.A.B.', u'play') #updated and showing correct song title from line 7
Command: pause
(u'A.T.A.B.', u'play')
Command: play 
(u'A.T.A.B.', u'pause')
Command:
```

My output appears to be one cycle behind and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Hi, because you're reading py_data as set before the second requests.get(). The results from the second requests.get are thrown away because no variable is assigned the return value

Answer (score 1):

Because that's how you've ordered it in your script. You always call the getstate endpoint, which shows the last command you executed, and you parse that result into `py_data`. Now, if you enter an actual command, you send that command as well, but then output the contents of `py_data` - which you haven't updated.

Assuming that the result from sending a command is the current state, you should call `json.loads` on that result in your else block, and print that.

**Edit** OK, here is a reformulated function that makes more sense.

```
def controls(cmd):
    if cmd != 'getstate':
        requests.get("http://volumio.local:3000/api/v1/commands/?cmd=%s" % cmd)
    volumio = requests.get("http://volumio.local:3000/api/v1/getstate")
    vol_data = volumio.text
    py_data = json.loads(vol_data)
    print(py_data['title'], py_data['status'])
```

Here you perform the command if there is one, and then do the getstate call.

Comment: Hmm.. well actually, the second requests.get() (the one that issues the command) does not return any data. At least not any useful data. Perhaps I should not be using the requests.get(), since I'm simply issuing the command with this line. Would requests.post() be more conventional (even though I am not pushing any additional data)? All this aside, I dont understand why py_data is not updated. Even after I move the getstate request below the command request.

Comment: It's not a question of whether get or post is more conventional, but of what the api is expecting. Normally you would use post for state changes, though. Note, I've updated the answer with some suggested code.

Comment: Yeah, I've changed my code to something that resembles your suggestion (I think)... It's too long to post here but it's in this reddit thread in the comments: [https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/69dsq1/code_help/] still seems to be something funky going on.

Answer (score 1):

```
def controls(cmd):
    volumio = requests.get("http://volumio.local:3000/api/v1/getstate")
    vol_data = volumio.text
    py_data = json.loads(vol_data)
    if cmd == 'getstate':
             print(py_data['title'], py_data['status'])
    else:
            r = requests.get("http://volumio.local:3000/api/v1/commands/?cmd=%s" % cmd)
            py_data = r.json()
            print(py_data['title'], py_data['status'])
```